# I am unable to make HttpClient Post with certificate based on cUrl

Tags: c#, curl, asp.net-core

I have the following cUrl command that needs to run in a c# .net Core environment.

```
curl -X POST -k https://example.com:8443/as/token.oauth2 \
-v \
--cert TPPCertificate.crt \
--key TPPprivateKey.key \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=TPP_test&code=9C6UrsGZ0Z3XJymRAOAgl7hKPLlWKUo9GBfMQQEs&redirect_uri=https://localhost/auth'
```

I have tried the following code but it is not sending the certificate to the server:

```
 var input = model as AccessRetrieveModel;
            var certFile = Path.Combine(@"c:\tmp\", "TPPCertificate.crt");

            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;

                var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\tmp\TPPCertificate.crt");
                var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(buffer, "Test", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                //add the cert to the handler
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {

                    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, cert, chain, errors) =>
                    {
                        //this verifies the server API cert against expected thumprint
                        return true;
                    };

                    var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",ClientID),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code",input.Code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri","https://localhost/auth"),
            });

                    // Get the response.
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                        $"{AuthenticationUrl}/as/token.oauth2",
                        requestContent);

                    // Get the response content.
                    HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

                    // Get the stream of the content.
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                    {
                        // Write the output.
                        var result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to add both the .crt and the .key file

**Update**
I created a .pfx file for the .crt and .key and tried to add it to the Request. It Is still being treated as not added.

also tried, where certificate is new certificate.

Are there any other ways to add .crt and .key like cUrl does?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
            var client = new RestClient($"{AuthenticationUrl}/as/token.oauth2");
            client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { Certificate };
            client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", ClientID);
            request.AddParameter("code", input.Code);
            request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://localhost/auth");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: You never send a private key over the internet.  It allows hacker to be able to decrypt the messages.  Private keys should be loaded in the code.

Comment: Hi @jdweng thank you for your reply. Then how does curl do it? And how would I load the private key in c# and then add the certificate to the request?

Comment: If you want to see how curl does it then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the curl headers with the c# app.  the data must be encrypted with the private key before sending.  Then the server has same private key to decrypt message.